# How to use .srt file to show subtitles in xcode

Tags: xcode4.3

I need to show subtitle under video in xcode.. I knew we can use .srt file to show subtitles..I can parse .srt file.. But my problem is I don't know how to make the text in .srt file to be show under video, How to set the time intervals .. Anybody please help me

Comment: Anybody know...how to use .srt file in xcode

Answer (score 0):

I got it from stack overflow link.... I forgot that link... code in that link is this-

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"srtfilename" ofType:@"srt"];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];

while (![scanner isAtEnd])
   {
     @autoreleasepool
     {
       NSString *indexString;

       (void) [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&indexString];

       NSString *startString;
       (void) [scanner scanUpToString:@" --> " intoString:&startString];

       // My string constant doesn't begin with spaces because scanners
       // skip spaces and newlines by default.
       (void) [scanner scanString:@"-->" intoString:NULL];

       NSString *endString;
       (void) [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&endString];

       NSString *textString;
       // (void) [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&textString];
                // BEGIN EDIT
       (void) [scanner scanUpToString:@"\r\n\r\n" intoString:&textString];
       textString = [textString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@" "];
       // Addresses trailing space added if CRLF is on a line by itself at the end of the SRT file
       textString = [textString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
      // END EDIT

       NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            indexString , @"index",
                                            startString, @"start",
                                            endString , @"end",
                                            textString , @"text",
                                            nil];


      NSLog(@"%@", dictionary); } }
```

I did parse srt file by this... I added UITextView on movie player(MPMovieControlStyleNone) view.... I did change text automatically by using  startString and endString using timer... I can only play and pause the player by custom play and pause button...